# [html&css]Why the background color will disappear when use margin-top: -50px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I add the class 'col-xs-12' into the div where id is "me", it will not stay at the center; then I remove the class, the div go to the center, but half of the background will  disappear, how to fix it?

There is the code:

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center" style="margin-top: -50px;">

        <!--There is the div what I want to put at center.-->
        <div id="me" class="center-block clearfix col-xs-12" style="
            height: auto;
            width: 220px;
            background-color: #5B0707;
            padding: 10px;
            color: white">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first problem's shoot:

[image]

And the second:

[image]

The website is: www.tengzeyuan.com

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue ina fiddle or share the link of a working site..

Comment: Please post all the required code to reproduce the issue in your question (needs to be in the question itself, a link to an external site is not suitable as it can go dead).

Comment: @Lal http://www.tengzeyuan.com

Comment: See my answer @LzxHahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
position: relative;
```

to the style for the div with id `me`

that is, the `<div>` would be like

```
<div id="me" class="center-block clearfix col-xs-12" style="
     height: auto;
     position: relative;
     width: 220px;
     background-color: #5B0707;
     padding: 10px;
     color: white">
            Text
</div>
```

See the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: It's worked! thanks!

Comment: Great..:)glad that it helped..

Comment: An explanation of the problem and its solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
The following will solve your problem.

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
#center{
     position:absolute;
     left:50%;

}
</style>
  </head>
<body>

<div id = "center"class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center" >

        <!--There is the div what I want to put at center.-->
        <div id="me" class="center-block clearfix col-xs-12 " style="
            height: auto;
            width: 220px;
            background-color: #5B0707;
            padding: 10px;
            color: white">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```